# sigma algebra or not?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

**Question:** If X = {Y ⊆ Ω given either Y is finite or its complement(Y^c) is finite}, then show that

(i ) X is an algebra
(ii) If Ω is finite, then X is a sigma algebra
(iii) If Ω is infinite, then X is not a sigma algebra

**Attempted answer**:
(i) ϕ, Ω ∈ X also, Y ∈ X, then Ω\ Y = (Y^c) ∈ X.

(ii) if Ω is finite and Y ⊆ Ω. We get Yi ∈ X. Then its union, U_(i=1)^∞ Yi ∈ X.

(iii) However, I am not sure what happens if Ω is infinite,
is X no longer closed under countable union? If not how do I show it?

Any hints, examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an issue with (ii) consider the even numbers in the natural numbers.  Would it be in $X$?  Could it be generated in a sigma algebra?

Comment: Consider for example $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$. The set of all even natural numbers is a countable union of finite sets. However, this set is not finite, and its complement is also not finite. Now generalize it to any infinite set $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

By the axiom of choice, if $\Omega$ is infinite then $\Omega$ has an infinite, co-infinite subset $A$ (i.e. $A^c$ is also infinite), and $A$ has a countably infinite subset $B.$ Now $C=\{\{b\}: b\in B\}$ is a countable subset of $X.$ But is $\bigcup C$ in $X$?